# What value should I use for host in a kubernetes ingress manifest?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have this yaml for an Ingress:

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: app
  namespace: ingress-controller
... omitted for brevity ...
spec:
  rules:
    - host: ifs-alpha-kube-001.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              serviceName: service-nodeport
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              serviceName: service-nodeport
              servicePort: 443
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - {}
```

In the above I set ...

```
    - host: ifs-alpha-kube-001.example.com
```

That host just happens to be one of my nodes.  I have three nodes.  I am pretty certain that this incorrect.  The ingress works but if I shutdown ifs-alpha-kube-001 the ingress stops working.  What should I set `host` if I want a high availability cluster?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What should I set host if I want a high availability cluster?

The idea behind the Ingress resource is using the *brower's* `host:` HTTP header (which is sent for every request HTTP/1.1 and newer) for virtual hosting, so you can create *one* load balancer, but point all of your DNS records at the one host -- versus having to create a new load balancer for every `Service` in your cluster

Thus, the `host:` header would be whatever DNS name you wished for the outside world to be able to reach your `Service` as; for example, if you have a website and a reporting web-app in your cluster, one `host:` might be `www.example.com` and the other `host:` might be `reports.example.com` but both would be CNAME records for `my-k8s-lb.example.com`

Comment: I have tried to create `LoadBalanced` services but they never acquire an IP and the IP stays `<pending>`.

Comment: That's a separate question, but is caused by you not having a `--cloud-provider=` on your apiservers or the cloudprovider isn't configured; the logs for `controller-manager` will say what's wrong

Comment: Yes that is the case.  I guess I'll have to figure out how to add a cloud-provider to my cluster.